# Setting Timeout on Close and Disconnect IBM MQ.NET Client

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

Is it possible to set timeout period for the code below:

```
private MQQueueManager queueManager;
private MQQueue queue;

   ...
queue.Close();
queueManager.Disconnect();
```

The reason is that sometimes the connection get stuck trying to close. The thread blocked on Close() or Disconnect().

**Update**

The client uses managed client, CCDT file, cluster queue manager and other features that might result in different settings.

Please provide code sample.

Can we change the timeout setting using similar method via APIs like below:

```
    int openOptions = Set possible settings here

    var properties = new Hashtable
    {
          Set possible settings here
    };

    _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(_queueManagerName, properties);
    _queue = _queueManager.AccessQueue(QUEUE_NAME, openOptions);
```

Comment: Once you combine the content from the other timeout question into this question I'll I'll provide a answer with the details above and reference KC pages where applicable.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks for the info. I will close the other one, once this is resolved. Can you please provide code sample, and web links so I can read it in detail, as I am new to this topic.

Comment: Please provide display of CLNTCONN channel from CCDT like this: `DIS CHL(channel_name) HBINT`.

Comment: I cannot provide now until next Monday. Does the information affect the solution?

Comment: can you provide the answer without it ?

Comment: It would explain what type of timeout you should be seeing with your current setup.  Also good to note what the current SVRCONN channel HBINT is as well.  I'll provide an answer with the details I have.

Comment: @JoshMc please see update 2.

Comment: Did you review my answer?

Comment: I am looking for settings on API level of MQ.NET client. I cannot understand most of your answer, especially abbreviations used.

Comment: There is no API  way to set it.  Any abbreviation in my answer is a actual MQ setting.   You can search the KC or google for more details.  If you have any specific questions please add them as a comment tp my answer.   I have provided how to accomplish what you want with specifics.

Comment: Pingpong, I have updated my answer with details of the two fixes (APARs) that IBM has released as well as clarified a few items.  If you have any questions please comment back on my answer and I'll try and provide an answer.

Comment: Pingpong, I have updated my answer further with new information as APARs IT25064 and IT25065 were pulled back and the fixes were merged into APAR IT26614. If you have any questions please comment back on my answer and I'll try and provide an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way the MQ client and MQ server decide to TIMEOUT a connection is based on the negotiated Heart Beat (`HBINT`) value for the running `SVRCONN` channel.  The negotiated `HBINT` is always the highest value negotiated between the `SVRCONN` and the client application.

**Note:** `SVRCONN` `HBINT` has a default value of `300`.

The TIMEOUT is determined in one of two ways:

1. If the negotiated `HBINT` is less than 60 the TIMEOUT is 2x `HBINT`.
2. If the negotiated `HBINT` is greater than or equal to 60 the TIMEOUT is `HBINT` + 60.

---

Specific to the area of .NET clients related to `HBINT`:

APAR IT26614 corrects the following three issues:

1. In either Unmanaged or Managed mode it is documented that if you are not using a CCDT the `HBINT` will use the value of the `SVRCONN` channel. In reality if not using a CCDT the `HBINT` on the client side defaults to `300` so this is the lowest `HBINT` you will see.
2. Specific to Managed .NET the client side `HBINT` cannot be lower than the `SVRCONN` `HBINT` the connection will fail with a 2059. This problem impacts both with or without CCDT.

   - with a CCDT you are unable to set the `CLNTCONN` `HBINT` to a value less than the `SVRCONN` `HBINT`
   - without a CCDT you will be impacted if the `SVRCONN` `HBINT` is set to `301` or higher
3. Specific to Managed .NET the client side receive timeout was being calculated in milliseconds not seconds.  In this case the defect has been present according to IBM for a long time, but did not present itself until APAR [IT16167: Managed .NET client application does not send heartbeat request to queue manager](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT16167) was introduced in 8.0.0.10 and 9.0.0.4 (IBM also confirmed this is present in GA 9.1.0.0).  The reason it was not previously a problem was that Managed .NET was never initiating the Heart Beat, the queue manager would always send the Heart Beat at HBINT + 5 seconds and the .NET client would respond.  Once this was corrected, the miscalculation of the receive  timeout presented itself.

> ```
> The fix is targeted for delivery in the following PTFs:
>
> Version    Maintenance Level
> v8.0       8.0.0.13
> v9.0 LTS   9.0.0.7
> v9.1 CD    9.1.3
> v9.1 LTS   9.1.0.3
> ```

As of July 12th 2019 only 9.0.0.7 and 9.1.3 have been released and can be downloaded from the following locations:

- 9.0.0.7 [MQC9: IBM MQ V9 Clients](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176)
- 9.1.3 [MQC91: IBM MQC91: IBM MQ Clients](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24044791)

---

Unless you are using a version of the `amqmdnet.dll` which includes the above APAR or you ask IBM to provide you with a IFIX for any lower version, the only way to accomplish a lower than 300 HBINT would require the `SVRCONN` `HBINT` to be set to a lower value in combination with the client using a CCDT with the `CLNTCONN` `HBINT` set to a lower value.  Based on unmanaged or Managed .NET you have two options:

1. With unmanaged .NET you can set the `CLNTCONN` `HBINT` to `1` and allow the client to to always negotiate up to the `SVRCONN` `HBINT` value.  You would then need the MQ admin to set the `SVRCONN` `HBINT` to the desired value.
2. With Managed .NET you would need the MQ admin to set the `SVRCONN` `HBINT` to the desired value, and you would then need to set the CCDT `CLNTCONN` `HBINT` to the same value as the `SVRCONN` `HBINT`.

---

If you are using a version of the `amqmdnet.dll` which includes the above APAR or you ask IBM to provide you with a IFIX for any lower version the following will be how things work:

1. If not using a CCDT the client side will use the equivalent of `HBINT(1)` and will negotiate up to the `SVRCONN` value.
2. If using a CCDT the `CLNTCONN` can have the `HBINT` set to `1` which would result in the same behavior as above when not using a CCDT, the `HBINT` will negotiate up to the `SVRCONN` value.

No matter if using a CCDT with `CLNTCONN` `HBINT` set to `1` or not using a CCDT where client side will use `HBINT(1)`, you will need to ask the MQ admin to set the `SVRCONN` `HBINT` to a lower value to accomplish a shorter TIMEOUT.

---

Example of setting `HBINT` on the CCDT `CLNTCONN` channel:

```
DEFINE CHL(CLIENT_CHL) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) CONNAME('1.2.3.4(9999)') QMNAME(ABC) HBINT(1)
```