# Windows 2016 WebSphere MQ Issues

Tags: c#, wcf, ibm-mq, windows-server-2016

We have a WCF .Net installation that has been working for years connecting to WebSphere MQ. When we switched to Windows 2016, we have been encountering some connectivity issues. The threads from the WCF application will connect and stay connected for about 5min and then they die. We can see the connections via the MQ browser, but consistently around 5-6min they all die. Was working fine on Windows 2012. If it was permissions I wouldn't expect any connections.

Client: 8.0.0.10 (latest version doesn't seem to help)

Lots of communication exceptions.

**Errors from WCF log:**

> ```
> WCFCH0306E: An error occurred while attempting to receive data from endpoint 'jms:/queue?destination=**Redacted server etc here**&persistent=2&initialContextFactory=com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi'
> The operation could not be completed.
> Review the linked exception for further details.
>
> The method MQBACK failed.
> A WebSphere MQ call failed.
> Please see the linked exception for more information.</Message><StackTrace>   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsSessionImpl.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>    at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsSessionImpl.Close()
>    at IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsSessionResource.RemoveReference(Boolean throwExceptions)
>    at IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsConnectionManager.Close(Boolean throwExceptions)
>    at IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsChannelListener`1.CloseInternal(Boolean throwExceptions)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>IBM.XMS.IllegalStateException: The method MQBACK failed.
> A WebSphere MQ call failed.
> Please see the linked exception for more information.
>    at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsSessionImpl.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>    at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsSessionImpl.Close()
>    at IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsSessionResource.RemoveReference(Boolean throwExceptions)
>    at IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsConnectionManager.Close(Boolean throwExceptions)
>    at IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsChannelListener`1.CloseInternal(Boolean throwExceptions)
>
> Linked Exception : CompCode: 2, Reason: 2009
> ```

Comment: Try 8.0.0.9, 10 introduced a defect causing those symptoms.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc we will give that a shot. Really appreciate the info.

Comment: If that solves it i'l write up a answer with the APAR number.

Comment: Also you should consider 9.0.0.3 (4 also had the defect).  8 had already had End of Service announced as April 30 2020, 9 has not been announced yet but I would guess 2022.

Comment: Ok, will do. I really appreciate the information!

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, still getting the same errors with 8.0.0.9.  Any other ideas? We haven't changed anything in the application for years.

Comment: We keep getting communication faults (Error Code 2009) "The communication object, IBM.XMS.WCF.XmsInputChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."

Comment: Hi, sorry this was not a resolution to your issue, the 5 minute disconnect matched up with a PMR I have open with IBM for Managed .NET.  In the error you pasted in the question it shows it is failing when calling MQBACK.  Do you know why it is backing out the transaction in the first place?  2009 means the connection was broken.  Do you know if WCF .NET runs in Managed or unmanaged mode?  You can tell on the queue manager channel status by looking at the `RPRODUCT` value,  MQNM is managed.  I read that WIndows default TCP KeepAlive is 2 hours, is it possible on your server it's less than 5min?

Comment: @JoshMc no worries. I greatly appreciate the help. I have asked the admin to try and see if there is more detailed info we can get from the MQ server logs. Not sure why it is backing out the transaction, definitely odd. I will see what I can find out about managed vs unmanaged and the TCP KeepAlive. Thanks again for the help. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: On 2012 we were using 8.0.0.5, but yeah it is working fine. We tried that same version on 2016 with no luck.

Comment: Do you have full client install or are you using the redist client?

Comment: @JoshMc I believe we are using the full client install and not the redist (8.0.0.9-WS-MQC-Win64.zip)

Comment: @JoshMc a bit more info. Still checking on managed vs unmanaged. Heartbeat set to 60 seconds, Keepalive set to 120 seconds, and disconnect if not active set to 360 seconds. Makes me wonder if the keepalive is not getting back to the client which is then causing an unexpected disconnect at 360 seconds (the 5-6min we were seeing). Still working with the admin. Queue server logs just showing channel to host ended abnormally.

Comment: Can you confirm if the time you see the disconnect on the client side is 360 seconds and the time the server sees the disconnect is before then at around 120 seconds?  I think I can explain the behavior you see based on a few defects that I have pointed out to IBM in this area.  See my answer to [Setting timeout for IBM MQSetting Timeout on Close and Disconnect IBM MQ.NET Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644990/setting-timeout-on-close-and-disconnect-ibm-mq-net-client/50678569#50678569).

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc. Were these things that were introduced in newer versions of the client? We are not encountering this in other environments with 8.0.0.5.

Comment: As far as I know the defects have been there to this day, the APARs are not yet part of a released version of MQ.  Is the TCP keepalive setting you referenced as 120 the windows client side setting or the MQ queue manager setting?

Comment: That was from the MQ queue manager setting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183010/discussion-between-joshmc-and-scarpacci).